# generate info.gz file from org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have the latest org-mode (9.1.3) which I installed to emacs through its git repository (specifically using) `straight-use-package`. The info file, however, was not installed. How can I manually create and install it?

I've looked at the git repo and it `doc\org.texi` is the source of the documentation. But it's not an `info.gz` file. I've tried the command `make doc` and I got the error that `no names found, cannot describe anything`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `make info` from the main org directory (the parent of the doc directory). But since you are on Windows (I assume), there might be things missing in the tool chain for producing the info file.

However, you can produce an info file in emacs itself: visit the `org.texi` file and say `M-x makeinfo-buffer`. This assumes that you have `makeinfo` (aka `texi2any`) installed. Note that the produced info files are uncompressed: if you want to compress them, you will need to do so by hand afterwards using `gzip`.

The info files are produced in ../../info relative to the doc directory, because of the following line in `org.texi`:

```
@setfilename ../../info/org.info
```

You can change that if you want them elsewhere (or move them after the fact).

Comment: I am on Debian Linux. I also tried to use the `make info` from the main org directory and it resulted in an error saying `fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.`. I looked for the package texiany with `apt search` and was not able to find it.

Comment: What does `make -n info` say? Also the program is called makeinfo or texi2any but the *package* is called `texinfo`. Try installing that and/or see if `makeinfo` is installed. If it is, then just say `makeinfo org.texi` in the doc directory and see what happens.

Comment: I installed `texinfo` and successfully created the info files with `M-x makeinfo-buffer`.